# how to select the elements of a matrix with some condition?

Tags: r

I have a one row matrix for example 1,5,19,13
I've tried select and subset, but I am not sure the exact method.
How can I select the elements >10 in this matrix, to form a new matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a logical slice:

```
R> j = matrix(c(1,5,19,13))
R> k = matrix(j[which(j > 10)])
R> k
     [,1]
[1,]   19
[2,]   13
```